# Some problems about the mexLasso function

Tags: matlab, robust

I am a student who is envolving in a research about robust visual tracking.
   And these days ,I had met a problem in my study.
 The teacher gave me a project of matlab code about the research, when I try to run this code, and the program error is as follows:

```
   ??? Attempt to execute SCRIPT mexLasso as a function:
    F:\L1_Tracking_standard_car\mexLasso.m

    Error in ==> L1Tracking_release at 95
            c = mexLasso(Y(:,i), [A fixT], param);

    Error in ==> demo at 46
    tracking_res    = L1Tracking_release( s_frames, sz_T, n_sample, init_pos,
    res_path, fcdatapts);
```

When I go to the program tracking, I found that mexLasso function does not exist, Only get an empty mexLasso.m  file and a mexLasso.mexw32 files.
My OS version is Windows 7 64bit,and the matlab is matlab 7.12.0 r2011a

Does anybody here knows the causes of my problem?

Anymore, I wonder if anybody knows who has the source code of the binary file mexLasso.mexw32.Because I thought that if I can get the source code of the file mexLasso.mexw32,then I could compile its 64 bit version myself.(I doubt that my os could not recognize the .mexw32 file.)

I hope my express clear enough to let you come to help me ,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think your analysis is basically correct - `mexLasso` is intended to be a MEX function, but MATLAB is finding only `mexLasso.m` which presumably contains help text. Unfortunately, the error you're getting isn't terribly helpful. As I see it, you have two options:

1. Obtain the source code for `mexLasso` and recompile on WIN64
2. Run the WIN32 version of MATLAB on your WIN64 machine

Answer (score 1):

the function mexLasso comes from the SPAMS toolbox 
http://www.di.ens.fr/willow/SPAMS/.

You can find the sources there and compile the mex file corresponding to your OS.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find `mexLasso.cpp` file in http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/downloads.html as Marial has already mentioned.

Then you can find and download the recent version of SPAMS.
A following stage is just to execute compile.m file on your MATLAB.

Finally you can find `mexLasso.mexw64` in the build folder.

Good luck.